# Most efficient way to paginate large amount of data in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, pagination, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an infinite scroll for posts that have rankings (similar to HackerNews), and I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to paginate/create infinite scroll with Firebase when there is a large amount of data.

The way I have been doing is that I request all of the data, sort them then limit the scroll to create an infinite scroll feel. Is there a way to do create this infinite scroll without having to request all the data then sort them?

The problem I see with this method is that if we have 100K+ entries, we would have to request and sort through 100K+ entries and that would not be nice. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ranking is a calculated value depending on the time since the post was created and the score a post has received you really only have two options. You can either get all the posts and calculate the rankings client-side (which isn't an option in your case) or you can calculate the rankings whenever an update is made to the post. Also, I'm giving my examples in Swift.

Structure of the DB for this example:

```
posts : {
  $post: {
    stats : {
      score : scoreValue,
      ranking : rankingValue,
      createdAt : timestamp
    }
  }
}
```

Concretely this means that when a new post is created you'll assign it the default score and calculate the ranking.

Since the ranking is now stored in the database you can simply fetch the top x posts by using

```
postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild:"stats/ranking").queryLimited(toLast: x)
```

or perhaps

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "stats/ranking").queryEnding(atValue: "lowestScoreSoFar").queryLimited(toLast: x)
```

Now, to make sure a post's ranking remains up to date you can simply update the ranking in the same operation (transaction) where you update the score.

```
ref.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) ->   FIRTransactionResult in
  if var stats = currentData.value as? [String : Any] {
    var score = stats["score"] as? Int
    var createdAt = stats["createdAt"] as? Long
    score += 1
    var ranking = calculateRanking(score, createdAt)
    stats["score"] = score
    stats["ranking"] = ranking
    currentData.value = stats
    return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
  }
  return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
}) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
  if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
}
```

A problem with this method is the fact that a post with a high score will keep floating at the top if no one votes on it. To deal with this Hacker News seems to be running a script on their server which updates the ranking of one random post in the top x every 30 seconds. You'd have to run a server and see which setting works best for your particular case.

Since the rating of all posts will evolve towards reaching 0 if you're using an algorithm similar to that of Hacker News you could try randomly updating the ranking of posts with a ranking above a certain treshold (this way you'll ignore older and irrelevant posts).

[Hacker News Algorithm](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-hacker-news-ranking-algorithm-works-1d9b0cf2c08d#.gkn1z9vhd)

[More info on the algorithm](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1781013)

[How often does Hacker News recalculate rankings](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8516135)

[How Hacker News algorithm really works](http://www.righto.com/2013/11/how-hacker-news-ranking-really-works.html)

Comment: Thanks @Pieter Laebens for your answer. I've thought about this method. However, if my points are only raw points and I want to paginate the posts base on rankings, as in the ranking is correlated to time as well (older posts get lower rankings), how should I go about paginating this data?

Comment: Is the score incremented in like a transaction or is that calculated too?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I knew that I needed to have a server-side code running.